# Need to install node everytime after login in NGINX server

Tags: node.js, nginx, glibc, pm2

I am facing this issue again and again, when i use ssh root@____________ after that i run npm or any other node command it shows

`node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)`

i have to install node using nvm and then run it, the error goes.... but after that i have to install pm2 package again that causes my website backend to stop every time when VPS reboot by my hosting provider. front end works well but backend stops because node is not available and in reults pm2 also stops

i have tried to install it globally but failed i have also added node version in package.json file but still it shows error